# using vector inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, exception, vector, android-asynctask

i have loop inside mt AsyncTask doInBackground method .

```
  @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            receive = new Vector<Sms>();
            sent = new Vector<Sms>();
            draft = new Vector<Sms>();

            try {

                String type, from, date, budy;
                Vector<Sms> receive = new Vector<Sms>();
                Vector<Sms> sent = new Vector<Sms>();
                Vector<Sms> draft = new Vector<Sms>();

                progress_status = 1;
                publishProgress(progress_status);

                Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, null);;
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                progress_status = 2;
                publishProgress(progress_status);


                do {
                    type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
                    from = cursor
                            .getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                    date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                    budy = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

                    // check type (1-inbox,2-outbox,3-draft) and set there views
                    int numType = Integer.parseInt(type);

                    switch (numType) {
                    case 1:
                        Log.d("inbox", "message");  
                        Log.d("inbox", numType + "");
                        //receive.add(new Sms(type, from, date, budy)); 
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Log.d("outbox", "message");
                        Log.d("outbox", numType + "");
                        sent.add(new Sms(type, from, date, budy));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Log.d("draft", "message");
                        Log.d("draft", numType + "");
                        //draft.add(new Sms(type, from, date, budy));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("eeeee", e.getMessage());
            }







            return null;
        }
```

this switch is inside the loop , if i remove the vector action (on receive and sent) it will run perfect .

but i do want to update the vector but i catch exception when i do .

"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

so in this code i posted as you can i put the receive in comment and the sent vector is active so the loop will run until the first sent will get to the loop so the log cat will look like that :

```
04-13 00:40:41.000: D/inbox(13953): message
04-13 00:40:41.000: D/inbox(13953): 1
04-13 00:40:41.000: D/inbox(13953): message
04-13 00:40:41.000: D/inbox(13953): 1
04-13 00:40:41.005: D/outbox(13953): message
04-13 00:40:41.005: D/outbox(13953): 2
04-13 00:40:41.005: D/eeeee(13953): Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

as i said the loop alone wont couse truble only the vector.add...

this is the e.printStackTrace();

```
04-13 01:01:08.080: W/System.err(14901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create       handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:739)
 04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):   at com.example.sms.Sms.<init>(Sms.java:18)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at com.example.sms.MainActivity$ShowDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:168)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at com.example.sms.MainActivity$ShowDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-13 01:01:08.085: W/System.err(14901):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete which makes it almost impossible to help you... Are you typing to display a Toast in your AsyncTask?

Comment: The ultimate result here is that you can't create a handler in any thread (AysncTask runs in its own thread) other than the main thread. I believe SMS is your own custom class? In it I believe you are creating a new Handler.

Comment: I added more code . i do not use handler and be honest i dont know how to even if i wanted to .

Comment: That helps, but I still don't see the problem. Do you display a Toast while creating a new SMS object? (Toasts are one of the most common reasons for seeing this message.) You should put `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch-block, run your app again, then post the new orange output so we can see what is happening.

Comment: no i dont have toast .

i will add e.printStackTrace() to my question .

Comment: `at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:739)` It looks like you are trying to create an Activity with `new Activity()`... which you cannot do.  Post your SMS constructor and mark which line is #18.

Comment: @Dimrix, what is line 18 in SMS? Can you post its constructor? I think your issue is there.

Comment: public Sms(String type ,String from, String mdate, String budy) {
  super();
  this.type = type;
  this.from = from;
  this.mdate = mdate;
  this.budy = budy;
 }

Comment: Does SMS extend Activity? It looks like it. In which case, you have a few problems here.

Comment: yes !!!! why ??? i dont know...but i deleted it  works perfectly now ! you are a genius , thanks alot !

Comment: ok , i was to soon to be happy . now it wont catch exception but the information is not added to the vector

Comment: Refer to my answer update.

Comment: "but right after the loop is over the size is 0 again" You are creating new Vectors with the same names in your try-block... `Vector<Sms> sent = new Vector<Sms>();`  These will be destroyed as soon as you exit the try-catch block, simply remove these duplicate Vectors.

Comment: sam you are currect again . thanks alot . you helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be extending Activity if you are not using it as a "Screen". You have remove `SMS extends Activity` and instead design SMS in a more data centered way. Activities are used to display aggregated data not store it.

Make SMS something like this:

```
public class SMS {

    public String type, from, mdate, body;

    public SMS(String type, String from, String mdate, String body) {
        this.type = type;
        this.from = from;
        this.mdate = mdate;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have any idea why as the loop ended the vector reset ?i check the size as the data added and it did add the rows . but right after the loop is over the size is 0 again